# MVC 4 routing can't find controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't find the controller route in my new MVC 5 app. I've been following along with a few tutorials and everything appears to be written properly, but when browsing the address in the browser I always get:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI "//localhost:50473/api/tile"

**/Controller/ProductController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using coal.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace coal.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
        public void GetAllProducts() { }
        [HttpGet]
        public string Tiles(string urls) { }
    }
}
```

**/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs**

```
namespace coal
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Default",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "api",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "coal", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I know I'm missing something, just can't figure out what it is. Any insight would help.

Thanks

Comment: The action is called `Tiles` instead of `Tile`.

Comment: I can't see anything in your routes that would direct the tile action to the product controller. a url of `/api/product/tiles` should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route mapping needs to allow mvc to work out which controller and action method you're looking for. This can be done in two ways, either you can have a `{controller}` and `{action}` in your route string, or you can specify a `controller` and `action` in the `defaults`.

So for example you could set up a route like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then the URL to your method would be `http://localhost:50473/api/Product/Tiles`, matching the controller name "Product" and the action method name "tiles".

Alternatively, maybe you want the URL you specified to match, in which case you could do the following:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Tiles",
            routeTemplate: "api/tile/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Tiles" }
        );
```

Answer (score 6):

The name of your method is `Tiles`, but you're trying to hit `tile`.

```
public string Tiles(string urls) { }
```

---

### EDIT:  Updated to include the ProductController in the correct route to use:

Also, your route is defined as `api/{controller}/{action}`, and your controller name is ProductController.

The url you should use is: `api/product/tiles`, unless you create a route that maps the `Product/tiles` action to the `api/tiles` route.

and your route should look something like:

```
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: It's not just this though, is it? It's actually going to be looking for a *controller* called `tile`

Comment: @BenAaronson, I updated it to also call attention to the use of the controller name in the url.